# Infinity while loop on using scanner hasNext method

Tags: java, eclipse

I created a JDBC project for a Restaurant...
The problem is it's going to infinity loop... I don't know what to do, I have been working on it for few days. The only solution I got is to scanner `hasNext` method but its also not working!!!

```
package com.restaurant.orders;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("WELCOME TO UR RESTAURANT");
        System.out.println("PLEASE, PLACE UR ORDER: ");
        ManageOrders.PlaceOrder();
        System.out.println("ANYTHING ELSE???");
        Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean c=true;
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("1. CancleOrder");
            System.out.println("2. CancleDish");
            System.out.println("3. ReplaceDish");
            System.out.println("4. DisplayOrderDetails");
            System.out.println("5. Nothing, Thank you!!");
            if(scanner.hasNextInt()) {
                int ch=scanner.nextInt();
                switch(ch) {
                    case 1:ManageOrders.CancleOrder();break;
                    case 2:ManageOrders.CancleDish();break;
                    case 3:ManageOrders.ReplaceDish();break;
                    case 4:ManageOrders.DisplayorderDetails();break;
                    case 5:c=false;break;
                }
            }
            if(c==false) {
                break;
            }
            else {
                continue;
            }
        }
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Think about what your code does if `scanner.hasNextInt()` returns false.

Comment: Hello, first of all thank you so much for your reply. I have done all the changes in the code. Added default to switch, changed ch input to string ( tried with char too) and removed ~~~ifelse~~~ at last but still the same .... ***Infinity loop....*** Could you please try executing and see.... U can just simply use print statement in switch cases...

Answer (score 1):

The loop becomes infinite because somehow a non-integer value appears in the input and therefore `hasNextInt()` is always `false`.
It could make sense to change the type of the expected input to `String` and use `hasNext() / next()` to read a string value.
Also, the code may be improved:

- `switch` statement is missing a `default` case;
- `if/else` statement is redundant and may be removed;
- `while` loop should not be infinite, it should check the status of `c` instead:

```java
Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
boolean run = true;
while (run) {
    System.out.println("1. CancelOrder");
    System.out.println("2. CancelDish");
    System.out.println("3. ReplaceDish");
    System.out.println("4. DisplayOrderDetails");
    System.out.println("5. Nothing, Thank you!!");
    if (scanner.hasNext()) {
        String ch = scanner.next();
        switch(ch) {
            case "1": ManageOrders.CancleOrder(); break;
            case "2": ManageOrders.CancleDish();  break;
            case "3": ManageOrders.ReplaceDish(); break;
            case "4": ManageOrders.DisplayorderDetails(); break;
            case "5": run = false; break;
            default:  System.out.println("Use digits from 1 to 5 please"); break;
        }
    }
}
System.out.println("Bye");
```

Comment: First of all thank you so much for your reply and yeah I have tried this code already. It's resulting in NoSuchElementException...

Comment: Do you use scanner instances created on `System.in` in the methods of `ManageOrders` and _close_ those instances? [Online demo](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/j7r) -- interactive mode has to be enabled

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the user input on that way:

```
package com.restaurant.orders;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("WELCOME TO UR RESTAURANT");
        System.out.println("PLEASE, PLACE UR ORDER: ");
        ManageOrders.PlaceOrder();
        System.out.println("ANYTHING ELSE???");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean c = true;
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("1. CancleOrder");
            System.out.println("2. CancleDish");
            System.out.println("3. ReplaceDish");
            System.out.println("4. DisplayOrderDetails");
            System.out.println("5. Nothing, Thank you!!");
            
            int ch = scanner.nextInt();
            switch(ch) {
                case 1:ManageOrders.CancleOrder();break;
                case 2:ManageOrders.CancleDish();break;
                case 3:ManageOrders.ReplaceDish();break;
                case 4:ManageOrders.DisplayorderDetails();break;
                case 5:c=false;break;
            }
            
            if(c==false) {
                break;
            }
            else {
                continue;
            }
        }
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```